# Context behavior for jinja2 blocks with included files

Tags: python, jinja2

I have difficulties understanding the context behavior when including files in Jinja2 blocks. See this minimal example:

**base.jinja2**

```
{% set foo="bar" %}

{% block content %}
{% include 'include.jinja2' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**include.jinja2**

```
{{ foo }}
```

Rendering *base.jinja2* produces the error `foo' is undefined`.

When I move the declaration of `foo` into the `content` block, the code renders correctly. So does it, when I move the `include` statement outside the `content` block, when I remove the `content` block around the `include` statement, or when I replace the `include` statement with the file's contents.

Why is that? How can I use the global *foo* variable in the include file inside the *content* block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [link](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/), section `Block Nesting and Scope`:

> Blocks can be nested for more complex layouts. However, per default
>   blocks may not access variables from outer scopes:
>   The reason for this is that if the block is replaced by a child
>   template, a variable would appear that was not defined in the block or
>   passed to the context.

According to the document and starting with Jinja 2.2 you can change this behavior using `scoped`.

```py
{% set foo="bar" %}

{% block content scoped %}
{% include 'include.jinja2' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I agree that this is somehow weird, compared to what we are used to. But this is an intended feature.

Generally speaking, include is only passed the context.  Since 2.1 it is
passed a derived context that is the original context + all the local
variables used before the include statement.  This also means that if
you just *use* a variable from an outer scope, Jinja2 will track it as
local now and pass it to the derived context.

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed. But why does it work without ```scoped``` when I don't use an include file and reference ```foo``` directly in my ```content``` block?

Comment: Generally speaking, include is only passed the context.  Since Jinja 2.1 it is
passed a derived context that is the original context + all the local
variables used before the include statement.  This also means that if
you just *use* a variable from an outer scope, Jinja2 will track it as
local now and pass it to the derived context.